# A better way to do group_by() comparisons (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I"m trying to code a conditional binary. 1 if the time series data is ALL post event or 0 if some of the time series is split before and after the event date. However, my data has about 400 groups with independent time series data.

I ended up writing this...

```
  # create loop index
  lau2 <- as.vector(unique(as.character(final.reg$FIPS)))
  # create empty matrix
  final.reg2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=0, ncol=18))
  
  for(j in as.character(lau2)){
    # subset data by FIPS code
    f <- subset(final.reg, final.reg$FIPS == j)
    
    # create conditional binary
    f$IS_NULL <- ifelse(sum(f$AFTER)==nrow(f), 1, 0)
    
    # bind back to empty matrix to recreate final.reg
    final.reg2 <- rbind(final.reg2,  f)
    
    print(j)
  }
```

lau2 is a vector of FIPS codes for UK Local Administrative Units. final.reg is a data frame with the time series information and information on the treatment event. final.reg2 is an empty matrix I created for the rbind(). Ideally, I wouldn't need to create final.reg2 and could just use some dplyr() functions to create the dummy variable.

The code subsets final.reg by LAU code then looks to see if the number of rows is equal to the sum of AFTER (another dummy indicating if the time series data in that row is a date after the event happened). If IS_NULL LAU =1 then we have no before group so I'll have to drop that LAU when I do my analysis.

It tried using group_by() and summarise() to speed things up. e.g.

```
final.reg %>% 
     group_by(FIPS) %>%
         summarise(
            nrow=n(HPI),
            sum.aft = sum(AFTER))
```

I have also tried doing just `n(.)` rather than giving another column name that has unique observations. R only throws an error when I include `n()` but lets me do the `sum()` operation. I know `n()` is a dplyr method and used within summarise so I'm not sure what the issue is. My final analysis will iterate over my original loop about 100 times and with 400 unique LAUs the time to process this short little bit in my code will substantially increase the time it takes to create my datasets.

Comment: `n()` doesn't take arguments - it's just the number of rows in the current group. I don't know what `HPI` is, but I'm pretty sure you'd either want `nrow = n()` (number of rows in the group), or maybe `nrow = n_distinct(HPI)` (number of distinct HPI values in the group).

Comment: It would help a lot if you would (a) provide a minimal reproducible example with some data, and (b) were more specific about the problem. It *seems* like the question doesn't really start until "It tried using `group_by`...". You say you got an error - what was it?

Comment: @GregorThomas Any idea why ```n(.)``` doesn't work but ```n()``` does? I was under the impression they could be interpreted as the same thing, whatever dataset is a result of the last pipe operation.

Comment: The error when I use ```n(.)``` is "Error in n(.): unused argument(.)"

Comment: `n()` **takes no arguments**. You're not piping an argument into `n()`, you are piping an argument into `summarise()`. `n()` is magic - it knows it's in summarize (or `filter` or whatever other `dplyr` verb) and knows what to do. `n(.)` is giving the whole data frame as an argument to `n()` - which takes no arguments - hence the error.